# JXBrowser JSFunctionCallback and IFrame

Tags: javascript, java, iframe, jxbrowser

I'm porting my jxbrowser integrations from **4.9x to 6.11.x**, and i've got a problem with the **JavaScript - JavaBridge** with The **IFrame**. I register correctly with the follow code, and work as expect when I call the function from js in the main page. But doesn't work when the function is called from js inside the iframe.

```
    browser.addScriptContextListener(new ScriptContextAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void onScriptContextCreated(ScriptContextEvent event) {
            final Browser browser = event.getBrowser();
            JSValue window = browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue("window");
            window.asObject().setProperty("resolveMsg", new JSFunctionCallback() {

                @Override
                public Object invoke(Object... params) {

                    String msgId = (String) params[0];

                    Builder builder = WrLocMsg.builder(msgId);

                    return builder.buildOriginalMessage();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by recovery window in this way:

```
JSValue window = browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue(event.getJSContext().getFrameId(),"window");
```